# When is Now() calculated

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a SQL statement in a way like this: Is the result of Now() the same in the complete statement? Or, if some sub-queries take several minutes, different at several places?

```
select 
     *
from 
     table_x 
          join (select * from table_z where <different criteria and y = now() ) tablez on <joincontext>   
where 
     <different criteria> and x = now()
union 
select 
     * 
from 
     table_x 
where 
     <different criteria> and x = now()
```

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL specification, it should be "calculated" once for the whole statement, i.e. you should expect to get the same value everywhere within the same statement.

Comment: Calculated may be the wrong term, what is the correct English term then?

Comment: I'd say evaluated.

Comment: The correct term should be `Evaluated`  because `NOW()`  is a function. So the function is evaluated once

Comment: @jarlh - are you sure? Because I was always led to believe that the ansi standard specifies `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. `NOW`() is non-standard (and doesn't exist in SQL Server, so I'm really confused by this question)

Comment: You could test it on a big table with  `SELECT *, now() FROM bigTable` all row will have same time

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, oops, of course I meant current_timestamp... Simply assumed now() had the same behavior.

Comment: Is there some version of SQL Server where NOW() is a valid function?

Comment: `now()` exists in both mysql and postgresql, so it might just be that this question is mistagged.